# Protocol Buffer Generated Java source with Errors

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have 3 `.proto` files under same folder, I plan to add `LowDataBalanceRequest`
and `MobileRequest` into `EventRequest

Command to generate Java sources:

```
protoc --java_out=/home/haifzhan/myproject/src/main/java/com/example/util star_event.proto ldb_event.proto  generic_event.proto
```

star_event.proto and ldb_event.proto can generate Java source properly with no error, but  generic_event.proto has errors as(**my point is to show Errors, so I attache images other than source code**):

- One error says `Descriptor` instance might not be initialized
- Another one is complaining bracket is expected.

[image]
[image]
Here's my `generic_event.proto`

```
import "star_event.proto";
import "ldb_event.proto";

message EventRequest {
    optional LowDataBalanceRequest ldbRequest = 1;
    optional MobileRequest mobileRequest = 2;
}
```

I am using **version 2.6.1**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. 
A related issue on Github[Java: Invalid code generated when referencing a file with no package statement](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/3114)

The error is gone after I add `option java_package` in all `.proto` files:

```
option java_package = "com.example.util";
```

Here's my full `.proto` files:

```
option java_package = "com.example.util";
```

**ldb_event.proto**

```
option java_package = "com.example.util";

enum RequestTrigger {
    LDB = 1;
    OTHER = 2;
}

message LowDataBalanceRequest {
    required string probe_id = 1;
    required int64 unix_time = 2;
}
```

**generic_event.proto**

```
import "star_event.proto";
import "ldb_event.proto";

option java_package = "com.example.util";

message EventRequest {
    optional LowDataBalanceRequest ldbRequest = 1;
    optional MobileRequest mobileRequest = 2;
}
```